# bundleReleaseJsAndAssets during Android release builds is taking infinite time

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native, gradlew

I am a UI developer and new to android, gradle and trying to figure out why to debug build ran fine and release build did not. Also, how can figure out this issue. 
I upgraded a legacy android app which included react native upgrade from v0.36.0 to 0.58.0 and trying to build the same

- The debug build runs fine
- The react-native command runs fine
  react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output xyz/index.android.bundle --assets-dest xyz/ --dev false

but when I try to run ./gradlew bundleReleaseJsAndAssets --debug
it runs for an infinite time.
I am using MAC, gradle 4.7

Tried project.ext.react = [ extraPackagerArgs: ["--max-workers=1"] ]
Tried org.gradle.configureondemand=true since I am manually able to bundle. 
Tried solution from following links

https://proandroiddev.com/bundling-react-native-during-android-release-builds-ec52c24e200d

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11696

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10078

```
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:28.941 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:28.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:28.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:28.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:28.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:29.241 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 6562177024}
21:25:29.242 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 6562177024}
21:25:29.242 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 954728448, Committed: 671088640}
21:25:34.240 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 6569676800}
21:25:34.240 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 6569676800}
21:25:34.240 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 954728448, Committed: 681574400}
21:25:38.941 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
21:25:38.941 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:38.941 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:38.941 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:38.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:38.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
21:25:38.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

If it helps, below is the result of ps -ef | grep "gradle"

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/x.y/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/gradle-4.10.1/lib/gradle-launcher-4.10.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.10.1
2029432261 16668 16658   0  9:24PM ??         3:48.65 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/x.y/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/25vec0eimrsoqjasnun8prrj45/gradle-4.10.1/lib/gradle-launcher-4.10.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.10.1
2029432261 16658  1910   0  9:24PM ttys001    0:14.87 /usr/bin/java -Xdock:name=Gradle -Xdock:icon=/Users/x.y/Dev/Mobile/myapp-android/media/gradle.icns -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew -classpath /Users/x.y/Dev/Mobile/myapp-android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain clean assembleRelease --debug
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem.

Reason:

- The babel was outdate for some reason (even being a RN dependence). Probably there was a dependency conflict.

Solution:

- Delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`
- `yarn`

Answer (score 0):

I would  first try to update/upgrade my gradle-wrapper.properties if this pops up either manually:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

or 
in your dir android run if you don't want to do that manually:

```
$ .\gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.4.1 --distribution-type all
```

It shows in your gradle.properties that it should be now:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

https://gradle.org/install/#manually

If all else fails I'd try to run it in a shell to see if it's my computer or if it's something else wrong with my project.

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to get through. 
The react.gradle file sets input to cache the result 
inputs.files fileTree(dir: reactRoot, excludes: inputExcludes)

This was the cause

Comment: Please explain your solution further, as I am having the same problem.

Comment: What he said ^^

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Rebuilding the `node_modules` directory and upgrading the `gradle` didn't work.

**What helped, was killing all `java` processes with `pkill java`.**

There must have been some stale process blocking the progress. ¯_(ツ)_/¯